# Get rid of extra header/banner on page.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help in getting rid of a header in this code. It keeps adding a second header/banner to all pages except `home`.

I'm really not sure how to go about this. Below is the code, and the link to site is http://ultratest.com/ultratest/about-us/

Code on "banner.php"

```
<?php
/**
 * Helper functions.
 *
 * @package Business_Kit
 */

if ( ( is_front_page()) || is_page_template( 'templates/home.php' ) ) {
    return;
} 

// Custom image.
$image_url = get_header_image();

if( !empty( $image_url ) ){

    $banner_style = 'style="background: url('.esc_url( $image_url ).') top center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"';

} else{

    $banner_style = '';
} ?>

<section id="featured-banner" class="overlay" <?php echo $banner_style; ?>>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="banner-title">

                <?php 
                if(is_page() || is_single() ){ ?>

                    <h2><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() ); ?></h2>

                    <?php
                } elseif( is_search() ){ ?>

                    <h2><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'business-kit' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h2>

                    <?php
                }elseif( is_404() ){ ?>

                    <h2><?php echo esc_html( 'Page Not Found: 404', 'business-kit'); ?></h2>

                    <?php
                }elseif( is_home() ){ ?>

                    <h2><?php single_post_title(); ?></h2>

                    <?php
                } else{

                    the_archive_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );

                }
                ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/breadcrumbs' ); ?>
</section><!-- #main-banner -->
```

Comment: Wouldn't the extra header be coming in from the header file? This html  is just the main content on the body of the page.

Comment: I'll take a look. Didn't think about that.

Comment: It doesn't look like it. When I inspect the page, the header/banner shows as <section id="featured-banner" class="overlay"> == $0

Comment: Well, show your page.php in the template-parts directory

Comment: I edited the post with the template-parts page.php. It was too long for the comments.

Comment: it's under banner.php under templates parts but i still can't seem to get rid of the banner

Comment: Hah.I figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!